# Integrating with 3rd party libraries

Tags: reactjs

I'm researching the potential of using React.js across our WordPress cluster (since WP Admin will move to it in the future). Reading through their website I'm impressed and it should suit what I need.

One thing I'm struggling with is examples interacting with other 3rd party JS libraries (in my case Gigya). Does anyone have good examples or documentation? Can we mix and match JS when the language is defined as "text/babel".

Cheers,

Al